# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended in stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SEC_YIELD_DOD_COMPARE_RPT(
    -- IN parameters
    reportingDate             IN DATE,
    P_PORTFOLIO_ID            IN NUMERIC,
    HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM IN VARCHAR2,
    derYieldCalcEngineCd      IN VARCHAR2,
    -- OUT for INSTRUMENT
    INSTRUMENT_CUR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
    -- OUT for PORTFOLIO
    PORTFOLIO_CUR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
AS
  instrument_sids instrument_sids_table := instrument_sids_table();
  portfolio_sids portfolio_sids_table   := portfolio_sids_table();
  queryPortfolio VARCHAR2(1500);
  queryInstrument VARCHAR2(1500);
  queryComplement VARCHAR2(1500);
BEGIN

  queryPortfolio:=' SELECT PORTFOLIO_SIDS_RECORD( c1, c2, c3 ) 
          FROM
            (SELECT PHS.PORTFOLIO_SID AS c1,
              NULL                    AS c2,
              PHS.TRADABLE_ENTITY_SID AS c3
            FROM PORTFOLIO_HOLDING_SNAPSHOT PHS
            INNER JOIN PORTFOLIO P     
            ON P.PORTFOLIO_SID = PHS.PORTFOLIO_SID
            INNER JOIN TRADABLE_ENTITY TE
            ON PHS.TRADABLE_ENTITY_SID = TE.TRADABLE_ENTITY_SID
            INNER JOIN INSTRUMENT I
            ON TE.INSTRUMENT_SID = I.INSTRUMENT_SID
            INNER JOIN TRADABLE_ENTITY_SNAPSHOT TES
            ON TE.TRADABLE_ENTITY_SID     = TES.TRADABLE_ENTITY_SID
            WHERE PHS.REPORTING_DT=:1
            AND TES.REPORTING_DT=:2
            AND P.CALCULATE_SEC_YIELD_IND = ''Y'')';

    queryInstrument:='SELECT INSTRUMENT_SIDS_RECORD(INSTRUMENT_SID, TRADABLE_ENTITY_SID) 
        FROM
          ( SELECT DISTINCT TE.INSTRUMENT_SID,
            TE.TRADABLE_ENTITY_SID
          FROM TRADABLE_ENTITY TE
          INNER JOIN PORTFOLIO_HOLDING_SNAPSHOT PHS
          ON PHS.TRADABLE_ENTITY_SID = TE.TRADABLE_ENTITY_SID
          INNER JOIN PORTFOLIO P
          ON PHS.PORTFOLIO_SID = P.PORTFOLIO_SID
          INNER JOIN INSTRUMENT I
          ON TE.INSTRUMENT_SID = I.INSTRUMENT_SID
          INNER JOIN TRADABLE_ENTITY_SNAPSHOT TES
          ON TE.TRADABLE_ENTITY_SID       = TES.TRADABLE_ENTITY_SID
          WHERE P.CALCULATE_SEC_YIELD_IND = ''Y''
          AND PHS.REPORTING_DT = :1
          AND TES.REPORTING_DT = :2)';
    -- Populate instrument IDs --

       IF P_PORTFOLIO_ID IS NOT NULL THEN
         IF HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM IS NOT NULL THEN
            IF derYieldCalcEngineCd IS NOT NULL THEN
                -- P_PORTFOLIO_ID AND HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM AND derYieldCalcEngineCd
                queryComplement:=' AND P.PORTFOLIO_ID=:3 AND PHS.HOLDING_SECURITY_ID =:4 AND TES.DER_YIELD_CALC_ENGINE_CD = :5';
                queryPortfolio := queryPortfolio || queryComplement;
                queryInstrument := queryInstrument || queryComplement;

               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryPortfolio BULK COLLECT INTO PORTFOLIO_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate,P_PORTFOLIO_ID, HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM, derYieldCalcEngineCd;
               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryInstrument BULK COLLECT INTO INSTRUMENT_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate,P_PORTFOLIO_ID, HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM, derYieldCalcEngineCd;
            ELSE
                -- P_PORTFOLIO_ID AND HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM
                queryComplement:=' AND P.PORTFOLIO_ID=:3 AND PHS.HOLDING_SECURITY_ID =:4';
                queryPortfolio := queryPortfolio || queryComplement;
                queryInstrument := queryInstrument || queryComplement;

               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryPortfolio BULK COLLECT INTO PORTFOLIO_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate,P_PORTFOLIO_ID, HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM;
               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryInstrument BULK COLLECT INTO INSTRUMENT_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate,P_PORTFOLIO_ID, HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM;
      END IF;
        ELSE
            IF derYieldCalcEngineCd IS NOT NULL THEN
                -- P_PORTFOLIO_ID AND derYieldCalcEngineCd
                queryComplement:=' AND P.PORTFOLIO_ID=:3 AND TES.DER_YIELD_CALC_ENGINE_CD = :4';
                queryPortfolio := queryPortfolio || queryComplement;
                queryInstrument := queryInstrument || queryComplement;

               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryPortfolio BULK COLLECT INTO PORTFOLIO_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate,P_PORTFOLIO_ID, derYieldCalcEngineCd;
               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryInstrument BULK COLLECT INTO INSTRUMENT_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate,P_PORTFOLIO_ID, derYieldCalcEngineCd;
            ELSE
                -- reportingDate, P_PORTFOLIO_ID

                 queryComplement:=' AND P.PORTFOLIO_ID=:3';
                queryPortfolio := queryPortfolio || queryComplement;
                queryInstrument := queryInstrument || queryComplement;

               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryPortfolio BULK COLLECT INTO PORTFOLIO_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate,P_PORTFOLIO_ID;
               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryInstrument BULK COLLECT INTO INSTRUMENT_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate,P_PORTFOLIO_ID;
            END IF;
        END IF;

    ELSE
        --FUND NUMBER IS NULL
        IF HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM IS NOT NULL THEN
            IF derYieldCalcEngineCd IS NOT NULL THEN
              --HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM and derYieldCalcEngineCd , NO FUND NUMBER
                queryComplement:='  AND PHS.HOLDING_SECURITY_ID =:3 AND TES.DER_YIELD_CALC_ENGINE_CD = :4';
                queryPortfolio := queryPortfolio || queryComplement;
                queryInstrument := queryInstrument || queryComplement;

               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryPortfolio BULK COLLECT INTO PORTFOLIO_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate, HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM, derYieldCalcEngineCd;
               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryInstrument BULK COLLECT INTO INSTRUMENT_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate, HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM, derYieldCalcEngineCd;
            ELSE
               --ONLY HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM
                 queryComplement:=' AND PHS.HOLDING_SECURITY_ID =:3 ';
                queryPortfolio := queryPortfolio || queryComplement;
                queryInstrument := queryInstrument || queryComplement;

               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryPortfolio BULK COLLECT INTO PORTFOLIO_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate, HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM;
               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryInstrument BULK COLLECT INTO INSTRUMENT_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate, HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM;
              END IF;
        ELSE
        --ONLY derYieldCalcEngineCd
         IF derYieldCalcEngineCd IS NOT NULL THEN
             queryComplement:='  AND TES.DER_YIELD_CALC_ENGINE_CD = :3';
                queryPortfolio := queryPortfolio || queryComplement;
                queryInstrument := queryInstrument || queryComplement;

               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryPortfolio BULK COLLECT INTO PORTFOLIO_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate, derYieldCalcEngineCd;
               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryInstrument BULK COLLECT INTO INSTRUMENT_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate, derYieldCalcEngineCd;

        ELSE         


        --  ONLY reportingDate


               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryPortfolio BULK COLLECT INTO PORTFOLIO_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate;
               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryInstrument BULK COLLECT INTO INSTRUMENT_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate;
    END IF;
    END IF;
    END IF;
```

When I execute this Stored Proc, it's showing me 
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512: at "FAYAODSDEV01.SEC_YIELD_DOD_COMPARE_RPT", line 112
ORA-06512: at line 14.

None of the lines is missing semicolon or any other syntactic stuff. 
I suspect the problem is in the string queryPortfolio or
queryInstrument.

However, I'm unable to figure out where the exact problem lies.

And for some reason, it is mentioning the line number 14.

Any thoughts?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @vc74 , yeah. It worked well. It was giving me output.

Comment: I don't really know Oracle, but you are using `:1` to `:5`, which seem parameters. But you seem to be "using" just two or three values.

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SEC_YIELD_DOD_COMPARE_RPT(
    -- IN parameters
    reportingDate             IN DATE,
    P_PORTFOLIO_ID            IN NUMERIC,
    HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM IN VARCHAR2,
    derYieldCalcEngineCd      IN VARCHAR2,
    -- OUT for INSTRUMENT
    INSTRUMENT_CUR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
    -- OUT for PORTFOLIO
    PORTFOLIO_CUR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR )
AS
  instrument_sids instrument_sids_table := instrument_sids_table();
  portfolio_sids portfolio_sids_table   := portfolio_sids_table();
  queryPortfolio VARCHAR2(1500);
  queryInstrument VARCHAR2(1500);
  queryComplement VARCHAR2(1500);
BEGIN

  queryPortfolio:='SELECT PORTFOLIO_SIDS_RECORD( c1, c2, c3 ) 
          FROM
            (SELECT PHS.PORTFOLIO_SID AS c1,
              NULL                    AS c2,
              PHS.TRADABLE_ENTITY_SID AS c3
            FROM PORTFOLIO_HOLDING_SNAPSHOT PHS
            INNER JOIN PORTFOLIO P     
            ON P.PORTFOLIO_SID = PHS.PORTFOLIO_SID
            INNER JOIN TRADABLE_ENTITY TE
            ON PHS.TRADABLE_ENTITY_SID = TE.TRADABLE_ENTITY_SID
            INNER JOIN INSTRUMENT I
            ON TE.INSTRUMENT_SID = I.INSTRUMENT_SID
            INNER JOIN TRADABLE_ENTITY_SNAPSHOT TES
            ON TE.TRADABLE_ENTITY_SID     = TES.TRADABLE_ENTITY_SID
            WHERE PHS.REPORTING_DT=:1
            AND TES.REPORTING_DT=:2
            AND P.CALCULATE_SEC_YIELD_IND = ''Y'')';

    queryInstrument:='SELECT INSTRUMENT_SIDS_RECORD(INSTRUMENT_SID, TRADABLE_ENTITY_SID) 
        FROM
          ( SELECT DISTINCT TE.INSTRUMENT_SID,
            TE.TRADABLE_ENTITY_SID
          FROM TRADABLE_ENTITY TE
          INNER JOIN PORTFOLIO_HOLDING_SNAPSHOT PHS
          ON PHS.TRADABLE_ENTITY_SID = TE.TRADABLE_ENTITY_SID
          INNER JOIN PORTFOLIO P
          ON PHS.PORTFOLIO_SID = P.PORTFOLIO_SID
          INNER JOIN INSTRUMENT I
          ON TE.INSTRUMENT_SID = I.INSTRUMENT_SID
          INNER JOIN TRADABLE_ENTITY_SNAPSHOT TES
          ON TE.TRADABLE_ENTITY_SID       = TES.TRADABLE_ENTITY_SID
          WHERE P.CALCULATE_SEC_YIELD_IND = ''Y''
          AND PHS.REPORTING_DT = :1
          AND TES.REPORTING_DT = :2)';
    -- Populate instrument IDs --

       IF P_PORTFOLIO_ID IS NOT NULL THEN
         IF HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM IS NOT NULL THEN
            IF derYieldCalcEngineCd IS NOT NULL THEN
                -- P_PORTFOLIO_ID AND HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM AND derYieldCalcEngineCd
                queryComplement:=' AND P.PORTFOLIO_ID=:3 AND PHS.HOLDING_SECURITY_ID =:4 AND TES.DER_YIELD_CALC_ENGINE_CD = :5';
                queryPortfolio := queryPortfolio || queryComplement;
                queryInstrument := queryInstrument || queryComplement;

               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryPortfolio BULK COLLECT INTO PORTFOLIO_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate,P_PORTFOLIO_ID, HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM, derYieldCalcEngineCd;
               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryInstrument BULK COLLECT INTO INSTRUMENT_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate,P_PORTFOLIO_ID, HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM, derYieldCalcEngineCd;
            ELSE
                -- P_PORTFOLIO_ID AND HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM
                queryComplement:=' AND P.PORTFOLIO_ID=:3 AND PHS.HOLDING_SECURITY_ID =:4';
                queryPortfolio := queryPortfolio || queryComplement;
                queryInstrument := queryInstrument || queryComplement;

               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryPortfolio BULK COLLECT INTO PORTFOLIO_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate,P_PORTFOLIO_ID, HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM;
               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryInstrument BULK COLLECT INTO INSTRUMENT_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate,P_PORTFOLIO_ID, HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            IF derYieldCalcEngineCd IS NOT NULL THEN
                -- P_PORTFOLIO_ID AND derYieldCalcEngineCd
                queryComplement:=' AND P.PORTFOLIO_ID=:3 AND TES.DER_YIELD_CALC_ENGINE_CD = :4';
                queryPortfolio := queryPortfolio || queryComplement;
                queryInstrument := queryInstrument || queryComplement;

               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryPortfolio BULK COLLECT INTO PORTFOLIO_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate,P_PORTFOLIO_ID, derYieldCalcEngineCd;
               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryInstrument BULK COLLECT INTO INSTRUMENT_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate,P_PORTFOLIO_ID, derYieldCalcEngineCd;
            ELSE
                -- reportingDate, P_PORTFOLIO_ID

                 queryComplement:=' AND P.PORTFOLIO_ID=:3';
                queryPortfolio := queryPortfolio || queryComplement;
                queryInstrument := queryInstrument || queryComplement;

               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryPortfolio BULK COLLECT INTO PORTFOLIO_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate,P_PORTFOLIO_ID;
               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryInstrument BULK COLLECT INTO INSTRUMENT_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate,P_PORTFOLIO_ID;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    ELSE
        --FUND NUMBER IS NULL
        IF HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM IS NOT NULL THEN
            IF derYieldCalcEngineCd IS NOT NULL THEN
              --HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM and derYieldCalcEngineCd , NO FUND NUMBER
                queryComplement:='  AND PHS.HOLDING_SECURITY_ID =:3 AND TES.DER_YIELD_CALC_ENGINE_CD = :4';
                queryPortfolio := queryPortfolio || queryComplement;
                queryInstrument := queryInstrument || queryComplement;

               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryPortfolio BULK COLLECT INTO PORTFOLIO_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate, HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM, derYieldCalcEngineCd;
               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryInstrument BULK COLLECT INTO INSTRUMENT_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate, HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM, derYieldCalcEngineCd;
            ELSE
               --ONLY HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM
                 queryComplement:=' AND PHS.HOLDING_SECURITY_ID =:3 ';
                queryPortfolio := queryPortfolio || queryComplement;
                queryInstrument := queryInstrument || queryComplement;

               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryPortfolio BULK COLLECT INTO PORTFOLIO_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate, HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM;
               EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryInstrument BULK COLLECT INTO INSTRUMENT_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate, HOLDING_SECURITY_ID_PARAM;
            END IF;
        ELSE
        --ONLY derYieldCalcEngineCd
            IF derYieldCalcEngineCd IS NOT NULL THEN
                 queryComplement:='  AND TES.DER_YIELD_CALC_ENGINE_CD = :3';
                    queryPortfolio := queryPortfolio || queryComplement;
                    queryInstrument := queryInstrument || queryComplement;

                   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryPortfolio BULK COLLECT INTO PORTFOLIO_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate, derYieldCalcEngineCd;
                   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryInstrument BULK COLLECT INTO INSTRUMENT_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate, derYieldCalcEngineCd;

            ELSE         


            --  ONLY reportingDate


                   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryPortfolio BULK COLLECT INTO PORTFOLIO_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate;
                   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE queryInstrument BULK COLLECT INTO INSTRUMENT_SIDS USING reportingDate,reportingDate;
            END IF;
        END IF;
    END IF;
```

END;

Try above code.

You had forgotten to add **`END;`** at the end of procedure.

I had added that.

It will surely helps you.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible for us to remotely debug your dynamically generated SQL. This is a problem you will have to solve by yourself.

Dynamic SQL is hard to code and hard to debug. The main problem is it turns compilation errors into runtime errors. But because the statement is dynamic there is no source to pore over until you find the bug.

However, you can make it easier on yourself by instrumenting your code. Put in some trace statement, preferably logging to a table or a file but using `dbms_output.put_line()` if that's all you have. Log which branch you go down. Log the generated SQL statement. Even log the parameters which are in play.

Having sufficient information to understand the problem is at least fifty percent of the solution.